# String to List<String> conversion returning incomplete values ending halfway with ‘…’

Tags: apex, list, data

List of string created with split(,) on a string variable, returns 10 values and the rest of the data is missing. Instead ‘…’ is there.

String str = ‘value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,value6,value7,value8,value9,value10,value11 and more values as such );
List strList = str.split(‘,’);

Now strList has values {value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,value6,value7,value8,value9,value10,… }

When reading this list in the same code as well the 11th string comes as ‘…’

Comment: can you show your code, any sample data ? or what have you implemented

Comment: Collections could be truncated in debug logs as well

Comment: toString on lists automatically truncate after a number of values. See linked answer.

Comment: @AmanPatil updated thanks

Comment: @sfdcfox the linked answer is for list to string, my use case is for string to list. In the linked answer join() is given as a resolution, same way what can we do for string to list?

Comment: @JPM `Splitting` the string creates a `List<String>`, which is why the list is truncated. If you want the entire thing, you need to `join` it back together.

Comment: How are you determining that it's the `string -> list` part that's the problem here? If you're using `system.debug()`, then the linked answer explains why that is. As a quick test, try `system.debug(strList.size());`. You should see that the size extends beyond what you can see with a `system.debug(strList);` (indicating this is just an artifact of `toString()`)

Comment: @sfdcfox thanks but is there any way to get the entire list, because I read a sheet attachment where at one point the row is taken as a single string. To determine the column number of one column header I’m splitting that string into list with ‘,’ and when I try to find the index of that column header in that list it returns -1 because after 10th column only ellipses ‘…’ is present and rest of the column names are not found

Comment: @DerekF thanks but it’s not with just System.debug, when I read the List I’m unable to read after 10 values the 11th value comes ‘…’ whereas I need to read the other values of list as well. This ‘…’ comes as 11th character when I store this in a rich text field as well

Comment: You're going to need to show real code, not pseudo-code. The behavior you're describing is what you'd get if you use toString() on a list, not a list of elements.

Comment: The issue would relate to this -> https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54V00007T48UdSAJ , here the resolution is given as to serialise the json object to eliminate the ellipses ‘…’ but in my case I serialised a json object and got a comma separate string as a result, as I want it as list I split it with delimiter as comma and store in a list of string. My issue is that the list string has ellipses again, not having original data after 10 values

Comment: My issue is that the list string has ellipses again, not having original data after 10 values - that’s not just in debug but also iterating through the list gives the 11th element as ‘…’ . @sfdcfox can u plz help

Comment: Yes, you're debugging a `List<Object>`. This appears to trigger the problem as described in the original answer. If you `JSON.serialize(a)`, the data appears as complete.

Comment: I don’t debug list of object, I serialize object, store it in a string, then split that string and store in a list, then use that list in two ways, one to store value in a rich text field which display ‘…’ as 11th value when there are actually 47 values, and another use is to iterate that list in code and find the occurrence of a value, which doesn’t work because the list holds just 11 values 11th being ‘…’. @sfdcfox any inputs here plz

Comment: Just as I said--you need to serialize/String.join in order to get all the values out. Trying using JSON.serialize to get the values you expect.

Comment: So we can’t process the values?

Comment: Let’s say if the string is ‘h1,h2,h3’, I want to get the position of h3, if I can get it in a list I can count the index and mark as index 2& position 3. How can this logic be performed @sfdcfox

Comment: `Integer h3index = 'h1,h2,h3'.split(',').indexOf('h3')` is such an example. Again, when you're in a collection, the string is truncated by toString. Use JSON.serialize or some other means.

Comment: Integer h3index = 'h1,h2,h3'.split(',').indexOf('h3') this too doesn’t work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152247/discussion-between-jpm-and-sfdcfox).

Comment: @sfdcfox Any regex can be tried to get the index of nth occurrence of a substring?